# Folder, File inventory in MacOS

Tags: macos, mac

Could someone help me list folder, subfolder and file names along with sizes in Macbook? It could be a command in Terminal or a unix script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command "ls -lahR ~/" in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The `du` command:

```
du -k foo
```

(disk usage) (in kilobytes ) ( of a folder named foo )